# c# creating instances of classes programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

is it possible to create instances of a class programmatically?

for example, I will need to create anywhere from 10-20 forms programmatically

so I will do:

```
   Form graphs = new Form1(dateStart.Value.ToShortDateString(), dateEnd.Value.ToShortDateString(),cbQCValues.Text,cbAnalytes.Text,cbInstruments.Text);
```

however the constructors are going to be different each time so I need to put this in a for loop

so I will need to run the above code how ever many times I need to. for example 10-20 times. I will need to have form classes graphs1, graphs2, graphs3...

is this possible?

Comment: You can use reflection. See Activator.CreateInstance. But if you really want to is another question. It feels like your concrete problem is the symptom of an architectural problem. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance.aspx

Comment: Are you merely trying to avoid the required typing, or is there some other more general problem you're trying to solve? Are these classes unknown at compile time?

Comment: You want to create many forms and call a different constructor each time? Use a for-loop and if-else. I don't see the problem.

Comment: @mark i need to display 10 different graphs thats all

Comment: @qwertie i didnt know that u can have multiple classes with the same name

Comment: @i am a girl  huh? No, you can't. So? Whatever the best solution is, there's not enough information in your question to find it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if I understand it correctly but are you after this??

```
List<Form1> forms = new List<Form1>();
for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
{
    forms.Add(new Form1(, ......))
}
```

Comment: Yes, it will work if you can figure out what value to pass in each loop cycle based on the value of i.

Comment: so how would i call the form.Show() method with this?

Answer (score 4):

I'd recommend you look into a factory design pattern.  There are many options, depending on what you are trying to to achieve.

You might find this useful:  http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/Patterns.aspx

Comment: +1: but IMHO an "abstract factory" would be the recommended option here.

Answer (score 1):

You can emit new classes at runtime, sure, but I suspect that you are asking the wrong question here.  If you only need to add random controls to a form, just create a new Form object and add those controls.  If you really need to create new classes at runtime, have a look at the System.Reflection.Emit namespace.

If you think this is a vague answer, you should consider writing a less vague question.  ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use the Activator class provided by the framework:

```
   public T CreateInstance<T>() where T: new() {

     return (T)Activator.CreateInstane(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().CodeBase, 
                                     typeof(SomeType).FullName)

    }
```